# I have roughly 30M rows to Insert Update in SQL Server per day what are my options?

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, sqlbulkcopy

I have roughly 30M rows to Insert Update in SQL Server per day what are my options?

If I use SqlBulkCopy, does it handle not inserting data that already exists?

In my scenario I need to be able to run this over and over with the same data without duplicating data.

At the moment I have a stored procedure with an update statement and an insert statement which read data from a DataTable.

What should I be looking for to get better performance?

Comment: BulkInsert is the way to go :)  You'll have to experiment to see whether to 1) set a unique constraint and ignore errors, or 2) clear your input of duplicates before attempting the bulkcopy.  IMHO...

Comment: Did you measure you existing performance? Is it bad? Did you find what is your bottleneck. 30M for 24 hours is 347 records a second. That's a tiny amount.

Comment: it's currently taking me about 16 hours. I have found some bottle necks but i'm still trying things out. Windows Azure SQL Database is not allowing me to create tables without primary keys and without clustered indexes. I wanted to try inserting raw data into a table with out any contraints and then merge into my production table.

Comment: SQL Azure requires PKs and clustered indexes because it is essentially using replication to manage HA across servers. Just an FYI.

Comment: @BrianKnight you're absolutely correct, thanks for the info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way to do something like this is to maintain a permanent work table (or tables) that have no constraints on them. Often these might live in a separate work database on the same server.

To load the data, you empty the work tables, blast the data in via BCP/bulk copy. Once the data is loaded, you do whatever cleanup and/or transforms are necessary to prep the newly loaded data. Once that's done, as a final step, you migrate the data to the real tables by performing the update/delete/insert operations necessary to implement the delta between the old data and the new, or by simply truncating the real tables and reloading them.

Another option, if you've got something resembling a steady stream of data flowing in, might be to set up a daemon to monitor for the arrival of data and then do the inserts. For instance, if your data is flat files get dropped into a directory via FTP or the like, the daemon can monitor the directory for changes and do the necessary work (as above) when stuff arrives.

One thing to consider, if this is a production system, is that doing massive insert/delete/update statements is likely to cause blocking while the transaction is in-flight. Also, a gigantic transaction failing and rolling back has its own disadvantages:

- The rollback can take quite a while to process.
- Locks are held for the duration of the rollback, so more opportunity for blocking and other contention in the database.
- Worst, after all that happens, you've achieved no forward motion, so to speak: a lot of time and effort and you're right back where you started.

So, depending on your circumstances, you might be better off doing your insert/update/deletes in smaller batches so as to guarantee that you achieve forward progress. 30 million rows over 24 hours works out to be c. 350 per second.

Comment: The only problem I have with this, is that my data doesn't come all at once and I have no way of knowing when I'm done.

Comment: @AlexandreBrisebois - Can you batch it, and process it every X hours?

Comment: thats what i'm trying to figure out. I have a few thousand processes that generate large amounts of data, this data is queued for import and is imported chunk by chunk.

Comment: @AlexandreBrisebois: see my amended answer.

Comment: great feedback, I will try the bulk insert in a secondary table and merge. at this point the problem is that I need to insert the 30M much faster than 24hs.

Answer (score 2):

Bulk insert into a holding table then perform either a single Merge statement or an Update and an Insert statement.  Either way you want to compare your source table to your holding table to see which action to perform